# Passwordprtect a php url based on query string

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection

I have a CMS system which runs lot of pages and url created for pages are like cms.php?id=xx, I would like to only password protect a page having specific id (say 9) using htaccess, i am kinda zero in htaccess so if code is bit explainative that will help me.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction

```
<?
    //* Check for values in $PHP_AUTH_USER and $PHP_AUTH_PW */

    if ((!isset($PHP_AUTH_USER)) || (!isset($PHP_AUTH_PW))) {

         //* No values: send headers causing dialog box to appear */
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Private Stuff"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Authorization Required.';
        exit;

    } else if ((isset($PHP_AUTH_USER)) && (isset($PHP_AUTH_PW))){

        /* Values contain some values, so check to see if they're correct */

        if (($PHP_AUTH_USER != "validname") || ($PHP_AUTH_PW != "goodpassword")) {
                //* If either the username entered is incorrect, or the password entered is incorrect, send the headers causing dialog box to appear */
                header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Private Stuff"');
                header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
                echo 'Authorization Required.';
                exit;
        } else if (($PHP_AUTH_USER == "validname") || ($PHP_AUTH_PW == "goodpassword"))  {
                //* if both values are correct, print success message */
                echo "<P>You're authorized!</p>";
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: this will popup the auth box as needed = you can add some extra php logic in and bobs your uncle

Comment: to avoid the core hack to open source CMS I am using I cant add any php code in its files, thats why I mentioned that I need a solution thats .htaccess based (sry if I was not clear in my question), but thats has to be htaccess solution not the php code. anyways thx for your reply.